# Add scrollview objects with text to UIViewController stortboard application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, scrollview

I'm new to iPhone app development and just developing an application.

I have story board application with tabs.One tab is associated with view controller.

Now, I want to add a scroll view object to the UI view controller; And, the scroll view object should display some text in it.On top of the scroll view I want to display an image and this is fixed.Only text will scroll.

How can I do it?

Comment: Anyway you simply need to add a UIImageView instance and right under it a UITextview (which is a subclass of UIScrollView)

Comment: Are you using storyboards? Are the image and text dynamic or static?

Comment: Yes,I'm using story board,And for the time being image and test are static only.Later, I may make it dynamic.If you have solution for both static and dynamic, then it would be great.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Drag a `UIImageView` instance from the library and add it to your controller
[image: ImageView]

Place the image view where you want in your controller's view

[image]

Select the image view and set its image in the attributes inspector

[image]

Drag a `UITextView` instance from the library and add it to your controller

[image]

Place the text view where you want

[image]

Select the text view and set its text in the attributes inspector

[image]

If you want to change the text and the image dynamically, you need to add outlets for them in your controller. That way you can access their `image` and `text` `property`s and change them.

Comment: I'm in metting.I'll try it after sometime.Thanks.